# Fazer algo após um script externo ser totalmente carregado via jQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `<script>` externo sendo adicionado na página via jQuery com:

```
$("body").append("<scr"+"ipt src='url_do_script.js'></scr"+"ipt>");
```

Esse script adiciona alguns elementos na página (algumas tags). O script funciona perfeitamente, mas ele é *assícrono* ao carregamento da página, ou seja, a página carrega normalmente sem esperar o que o script irá retornar. Porém eu preciso manipular algumas tags retornadas por este `.js` **assim que elas estiverem disponíveis**.

O problema é que não encontrei uma forma de saber quando esse script já foi totalmente carregado na página com jQuery.

Com JavaScript puro eu consigo saber adicionando o script via `document.createElement` e `appendChild`. Basta fazer um `.onload`:

```
var e = document.createElement("script");
e.src = "url_do_script.js";
document.body.appendChild(e);

e.onload = function(){
   // o script foi totalmente carregado
}
```

Como fazer algo com o `.append` do jQuery? Já tentei outras formas como `.get`, `.load` e `.ajax` mas não funciona devido aos CORS (*Cross-origin resource sharing*).

Tentei colocar um `onload="funcao()"` no `<script>` e também não funcionou.

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso ou há uma outra forma usando jQuery sem ser com `.append`?

Comment: O fato de `onload` não funcionar, é que o elemento [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) não possui esse evento. Quando você utiliza com `createElement`, ele está criando um objeto com suporte a esse evento, não necessariamente criando o elemento em si. Já tentou com o [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)? Você também pode criar [extender o jquery](https://gist.github.com/NecoleYu/5606796)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver a questão com a dica do [@Valdeir Psr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/99718/valdeir-psr). Bastou adicionar o `getScript` logo após o `append` que o código reconheceu que os elementos foram carregados na página:

```
$("body").append('<scr'+'ipt src="url_do_script.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
$.getScript( "url_do_script.js", function() {
   // fazer algo após o script ter sido carregado
});
```

Não apresentou erro de CORS nem nada. Funcionou perfeitamente.

### ATUALIZAÇÃO

Verdade que fazendo um `append` e usando `getScript`, o script estava sendo chamado 2 vezes.

Como é preciso existir a tag `<script>` completa na página (`<script src="url_do_script.js"></script>`) senão ele não funciona neste caso específico, pois ele ainda possui um `id` (`<script id="id_qualquer" src="url_do_script.js"></script>`) e é baseado nesse `id` que o script funciona, contornei o problema da seguinte forma:

```
$("body").append('<script id="id_qualquer"></scr'+'ipt>');
$("#id_qualquer").attr("src","url_do_script.js");
$.getScript("url_do_script.js")
.done(function(){
   // fazer algo após o script ter sido carregado;
});
```

Adicionei o `src` do script via `id` e executei no `getScript` após o `.done`. Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Não faz sentido usar append e getScript ao mesmo tempo, você está mandando carregar o arquivo duas vezes.

Comment: @bfavaretto Verdade. Embora estivesse funcionando, eu verifiquei via console que estava retornando 2 vezes uma informação do script. Fiz as modificações acima e agora funciona sem duplicidade. Obg!

Comment: Mas continua carregando duas vezes. Veja a aba "rede" do seu console. Provavelmente uma das duas requisições virá do cache, mas mesmo assim é estranho deixar o código desse jeito. Se a sua tag script tem um id, você pode pegar esse ID por JS e tratar o carregamento com um `onload` desse elemento, mais ou menos como você mostrou na pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu testei antes, realmente estava requisitando duas vezes, pois retornava um erro 2x. Depois da mudança, só retornou 1x e consegui alterar o que eu queria. Bom, eu tentei pelo onload com uma função `onload="funcao()"` e sequer entrou na função. É porque trata-se de um serviço de banner de propaganda e só funciona desse modo. A programação do .js deles exige que haja a tag na página com o id específico e tudo, senão não funciona. Desta forma que fiz, o script não surte efeito ao colocar o src separado. Só surte efeito no getScript. Valeu!

Comment: @bfavaretto resumindo, o que fiz foi apenas construir a tag... a execução se dá no getScript. Abs!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/dajakilufa/edit?html,output

Comment: @bfavaretto Com `document.write` o navegador bloqueia o acesso ao script.

Comment: Então tenta com append, mas sem o getscript

Comment: @bfavaretto Já tentei de tudo rs... com append o onload não funcionou. Como eu disse, não chama a função no onload.