# O que isso significa: ".append('<scr'+'ipt .. "?

Tags: javascript

Ontem foi feita essa pergunta: [Fazer algo após um script externo ser totalmente carregado via jQuery append](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267030). Olhando a pergunta e sua resposta, o seguinte trecho de código me chamou a atenção:

```
$("body").append("<scr"+"ipt src='url_do_script.js'></scr"+"ipt>");
```

Qual o significado e a importância dessa concatenação ?

Não poderia simplesmente fazer direto:

```
$("body").append("<script src='url_do_script.js'></script>");
```

Comment: Pode também fazer um escape na barra `barra` do `</script>`, assim: `$("body").append("<script src='url_do_script.js'><\/script>");`

Comment: Deve ter uns 15 anos que faço assim `<scr"+"ipt`, quando aprendi, e nunca me preocupei em me reciclar... nunca notei tb que só precisava fazer isso no `<\script>` como citou o Guilherme. Mas agora vou passar a usar a forma acima, com escape. Achei bem mais simples.

Comment: Até então eu nunca tinha visto isso rsrs.

Comment: Mts anos atras eu trabalhei numa empresa de publicidade web e as agencias me mandavam os scripts assim pra colocar no site. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é usado quando o script é colocado diretamente dentro do HTML. Por exemplo, se fizer isto:

```
<script>
$("body").append("<script src='url_do_script.js'></script>");
</script>
```

O motor de renderização de HTML do navegador vai pensar que o script terminou em

```
...</script>");
```

quando na verdade ele terminou em

```
...);
</script>
```

Veja o teste:

```html
<script>
document.write("<script src='url_do_script.js'></script>");
</script>
```

Então, quando divide em duas strings e concatena, fará com que não atrapalhe o motor de renderização.

No entanto, é importante notar que isto **não é** necessário na tag de abertura:

```
"<scr"+"ipt
```

Pois o script só irá falhar a renderização e execução se for na tag de fechamento. Outra coisa interessante é que ao invés de usar o concatenar `</scr" + "ipt>`, você pode simplesmente usar os comentários HTML, assim:

```
<script>
<!--
$("body").append("<script src='url_do_script.js'></script>");
-->
</script>
```

Veja o teste:

```html
<script>
<!--
document.write("<script src='url_do_script.js'></script>");
-->
</script>
```

Se você notou isto dentro de um `.js` então é um equivocuo do programador, dentro de `.js` você pode escrever `</script>` tranquilamente em strings que não irá afetar nada.